# How to get 200mA/6v supply for MG-811 sensor from 2A/5vdc psu in small form factor?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I have a wall mounted raspberry pi, which has a 5vdc cable running into it, and that supply is rated for 2A. I'd like to add a CO2 sensor to the mix, and I've got a [MG-811 to hand](http://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=mg-811-co2-gas-sensor-module)

That component requires a heating current of 200mA at 6v +/- 0.1v according to the [datasheet.](http://sandboxelectronics.com/files/SEN-000007/MG811.pdf)

so basically I think am looking for a boost converter from 5vdc to 6vdc, and can handle say, 300mA. (I am not taking the supply from the pi 5v rail, but instead directly from the psu 5v line)

Is there a standard chip, or design for this?

Comment: There are many cheap boost converters on your online retailer of choice. At a 1V difference, you may need an LDO after the boost converter (which has the advantage of reducing noise). Or you could design your own boost converter, there are thousands of possible parts.

Comment: Are you using the complete module you linked to or only the MG-811 sensor?

Comment: I am using the complete module

Comment: I think its going to need 12v according to the other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=147) page it appears that the heating connector and the following circuits accept 7.5 to 12 V, so I suggest hooking it up to a 12 V wall wart.